# "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance": Adding either an Array or Object to an Array

Tags: javascript

So, to add one array to another in Javascript there is:

**concat()**

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var z = x.concat(y);
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c']  (remains unchanged)
// y = ['d', 'e', 'f']  (remains unchanged)
// z = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

**push.apply()**

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
x.push.apply(x, y);
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
// y = ['d', 'e', 'f']  (remains unchanged)
```

***...spreadOperator***

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var z = [...x, ...y];
// x = ['a', 'b', 'c']  (remains unchanged)
// y = ['d', 'e', 'f']  (remains unchanged)
// z = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

---

However, let's say that `var x` is an `Array` of `Objects`, and `var y` could ***either*** be an `Array` of more `Objects` ***or*** an `Object` instance...

Q.) I was wondering if there is a quick method that can handle the creation of a new `Array` from either two Arrays or one Array and a singular object...? I assumed the following might work:

```
let x = []
let y = {} OR []
let z = [...x, ...y];
```

When `y` is an `Array`, this is fine, but when y is an `Object` we would see the `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`...so, are there any possible methods to avoid such a scenario?

Comment: You can check if it is array then only concat them using Array.isArray();

Comment: You already found a solution: `concat`. It takes either an array or anything else as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Harmandeep said, this could be an implementation:

```js
const concat = (a,b) => [
  ...a,
  ...(Array.isArray(b) ? b : [b])
]

console.log(
  concat([{a:'a'}], [{b:'b'}]),
  concat([{a:'a'}], {b:'b'}),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let x = ['a', 'b']
let a = {}
let b = [{}]
console.log(x.concat(a))
console.log(x.concat(b))
```

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

```
let x = ['a','b']
let y = {} OR [{}]
let z = ...;
```

If you are expecting

```
z = ['a','b',{}]
```

Array.prototype.concat can solve this.

```
let z = x.concat(y)
```

[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) handles arrays and non arrays and append them accordingly

Answer (score 1):

> are there any possible methods to avoid such a scenario?

Yes, [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
let y: object | Array<object>  = {}
let z: Array<any> = [];

if(y instanceof Array) {
   let z = [...x, ...y];
}
```